# No WiFi in Linux Mint Xfce

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, 64-bit, xfce, linux-mint

I just installed Linux Mint (Debian Edition) Xfce x64 on my laptop, in preparation of getting my new computer for Christmas. Anyways, I am trying to connect to wireless, but I can't seem to get it to work. I would attach the output of `inxi -F` and `lsmod`, but it would take me a while to manually type it into the computer I'm on right now. My card is a Broadcom BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller, and I followed [this tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/218) (with downloaded .deb files) but most of the commands ended in error.

Comment: Don't you have any access to a wired connection for your laptop? Ubuntu and Mint come with a "install new drivers" application that should take care of that automatically.

Comment: @screener thanks for answering, I'll try that later.

Comment: The wired connection isn't working now. The (useless) network manager has an x on its icon.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should try **The Great Dead NIC Workaround**!  A ten minute visit to your friend's house and a thumb drive.